# Calculate norm $1$ of $f(x)=2x^3+3x^5$ belonging to C[-1,1]

Tags: normed-spaces

Calculate norm $1$ of $f(x)=2x^3+3x^5$ that belongs to $C[-1,1]$.

As norm $1$ is called integral norm, I calculated the value of the function for the given interval, and the answer I get is zero.

But the norm of a function is zero iff the vector itself is zero.... so how do I calculate it?

Comment: $\|f\|_1 = \int\limits_{-1}^1 |f(x)|dx$, not $\int\limits_{-1}^1 f(x)dx$.

Comment: however the absolute value of the funcion does have any change

Answer (score 2):

$$2x^3+3x^5=x^3(2+3x^2)\geq 0\iff x\in[0,1]$$
hence

$$||f||_1=\int_{-1}^1|f(t)|dt=-\int_{-1}^0f(t)dt+\int_0^1f(t)dt=2$$